# How emacs know that file came from git repository?

Tags: git, emacs

I didn't install anything for git and when I open a file from git repository Emacs show `Git:<BRANCH NAME>` in modeline. How Emacs know that it's git repo? I'm using Emacs 24.3.1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `vc` package calls the `vc-git-registered` function to check, is the file is registered in git.  You can find this function in the `vc-git.el` module.  The module itself is loaded first when you access a file in the directory that belongs to Git by using the code `(vc-find-root file ".git")` that is specified in the autoload section of the `vc-git`

Comment: Furthermore, `vc` (which is built in) [supports many other version control systems](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Version-Control.html) including Mercurial, Subversion, Bazaar, CVS, ...

Comment: Yes, the VC is great package, although I personally prefer concrete implementations, like the `magit` for git, etc.  For distributed VCS, there were before the DVC package that tried to abstract the common commands for distributed VCS

Comment: I agree that Magit is wonderful, but `vc` has its place. It's a good default IMO, and provides a somewhat consistent interface across backends.

Comment: Besides, `vc` provides the foundation for great packages such as [diff-hl](https://github.com/dgutov/diff-hl).